# How to find port number for a particular process id in unix?

Tags: pid, ps, netstat, uname

> In UNIX OS, how can I find the port number when i know the process name or pid ?

Answer (score 19):

```
netstat -pl | grep NAME_OR_PID
```

Comment: specifying the -p flag is usually followed by the protocol

Comment: @unekwu incorrect. Go read the man page. `-p, --program: Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.` You're thinking of `--protocol` which is different.

Comment: I get `netstat: l: unknown or uninstrumented protocol` when I run this on my computer

Comment: @unekwu then you have a non-standard netstat implementation. Mine is part of the "net-tools 2.10 alpha" suite, running under Arch Linux.

Comment: I see. Its different for OSX. I tried to upvote but it says I can't upvote until it is edited. If you include it doesn't work for mac, I'll upvote again.

Answer (score 0):

ss -plnt | grep PID | gawk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'